# check the convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, divergent-series

So I have the following series: 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{e^n}{e^{n\sqrt[n]{n}}(ln(n))^2}$$
I thought that this series does not converge. $\sqrt[n]{n}\rightarrow 1$ so I thought that for large $n$ it will act like $\sum\frac{1}{ln(n)^2}$.
But I checked this with wolframalpha and it told me that this series converges.

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Test $\dfrac{e^n}{e^{n\sqrt[n]{n}}}$ for individual values of $n$ and you will find it is less than $\dfrac1n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt[n]{n}=\exp((\ln n)/n)\geqslant1+(\ln n)/n$ hence $n\sqrt[n]{n}\geqslant n+\ln n$ and the $n$th term of the series is at most $$\frac{\mathrm e^n}{\mathrm e^{n+\ln n}(\ln n)^2}=\frac1{n(\ln n)^2},$$ from which the convergence of the series follows.

> Where did I make a mistake?

When you "deduced" from $\sqrt[n]{n}\to1$ (true) that $\mathrm e^{n\sqrt[n]{n}}/\mathrm e^n\to1$ (false).

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Try Cauchy or Integral test.

Comment: Cauchy test? Seems like a nice dead-end to send the OP to.